# How to avoid org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a method

```
@Transactional
public void initCityData(List<StoreDataVO> storeDataVos, City city) throws Exception {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Transaction txn = session.getTransaction();

    for (int i = 0; i < storeDataVos.size(); i++) {
        StoreDataVO storeDataVO = storeDataVos.get(i);
        processStore(city, storeDataVO);
        if (i % 10 == 0) {
            txn.commit();
            txn = session.beginTransaction();
        }
    }
    txn.commit();
    // spring will commit it in the end
    session.beginTransaction();
    logger.info("Store save done");
}
```

This method throws exception How to avoid org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using both declarative and programmatic transaction demarcation.

If you are using @Transactional, Spring will manage your transactions for you so you don't need calls such as beginTransaction and commit.

Comment: The number of store in (List<StoreDataVO> storeDataVos) is around 1000. It takes 20 mins for this method to get completed. So partial commits like committing after processing every 10 store is important.

Comment: Should I remove @Transactional and then try?

Comment: You can. You have to make a decision on managing your own transactions or letting Spring do it. Personally, I'd go with Spring. Regardless of that, 20 minutes to complete this method is alarming and committing intermittently isn't going to improve its performance.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done wrong here is that you have the whole method Transactional by annotation `@Transactional` so Spring will automatically handle this with all necessary steps like bigin end rollback etc.

Now you have explicitly stated a transaction inside a transaction, and when you do `txn = session.beginTransaction();`, the code gets break and it will throw an exception since the transaction has already started because of the annotation specified at the method level.

So either you remove the method level annotation or remove the transaction in your method.